# Печать с модального окна

Tags: html, css, print

С помощью fancybox делаю модал,в нем есть

как распечатать его с помощью кнопки на которой есть print().

попытался через @media-но все равно лепит на страницу и основную и модалку.

```css
@media print {
  /* Стиль для печати */
  {
    display: none;
  }
  .print_page {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужна более точная настройка и вы пропустили селектор * в начале.

```
@media print {
  /* Стиль для печати */
  * {
    display: none;
  }
  .print_page {
    display: block;
  }
  .print_page * {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: с * {
    display: none;
  } выдает ошибку предварительного просмотра-убираешь,выползает лишнее

Comment: Вообще да. Но это лишь примерное решение. Вам нужно четко прописать, какие именно блоки вы хотите скрыть, а какие показать. Например через запятую перечислить что скрываем: .header, .footer, .content {display: none;} и т.д.

Comment: сделал так body>*{display: none;}-но теперь отобржается в подобном виде(см.пост)-блок fancy отображается в зависимости от того как окно браузера открыто(resize у него какой-то висит). то что вверху вылазит-это на тестовой версии,на это пофиг

Comment: Потому то я и говорю, что нужно настроить четко, а не бить по площадям селекторами вроде *.